# Distinct roots of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let a be a nonzero real number. Deﬁne $f(x) =x^4-6a^2 x^2+8a^3x-3a^4$

for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ . Then, the number of distinct real roots of $f(x) = 0$ is

(A) 1 (B) 2 (C) 3 (D) 4.

We can either solve this by factorisation step-by-step. The answer I got is (B)Two $(-3a,a)$.

Is there any shortcut to solve this?
(I am thinking, may be Vieta's Formulas or something like that which I don't know now)

Comment: You have four roots $a,a,a,-3a$ but only $2$ are distincts. Since $a$ is a root, did you use the plolynomial division in order to deflate the polynomial ?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Nature_of_the_roots

Comment: You can use the rational roots theorem to conclude that the rational roots must be factors of $3a^4$.  Then use synthetic division to check.  Once you find one that divides evenly, you've reduced the degree of the poly.  Find another and reduce to degree 2 then use the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $x=ay$ and divide by $a^4\ne0$ to obtain $y^4-6y^2+8y-3=0$. So at least the number of roots does not depend on $a$. To look for rational roots, you need only check the divisors of $-3$, that is $-3,-1,1,3$. Two of these are indeed roots and the corresponding linear factors can be divided off, leaving $y^2-2y+1$ (at which point one facepalms that one forgot to check for multiple roots).

Alternatively, you can suspect right away that multiple roots occur. Those are also roots of $f'(x)=3x^3-12a^2x+8a^3$. Find $\gcd(f,f')$ by euclidean algorithm - it is $(x-a)^2$.